# In Laravel, how can you use a Gate if you're using custom authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization, laravel-gate

I would like to use Gates in Laravel 8, but we're using custom authentication, so Laravel doesn't know what $user record to pass into the Gate.  So how can I tell Laravel that a certain user is currently logged in, so the correct user record will be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did:

In `\App\Models`, I made a User class that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

I also set protected properties in that class of `$table` and `$primaryKey` to specify my custom table name and primary key name.

Then in my middleware, where I check to see if the user is logged in, if he or she is, then I run this:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::login(\App\Models\User::find($userId))
```

When I do all this, I can use `Auth::user()` wherever I want.  Presumably, gates will now work without specifying the user every time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `forUser` method:

```
Gate::forUser($user)->allows('update-post', $post);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates) of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Kenny, but in the blade, I would like to use simply @can("...").  It would be really handy to not have to specify the user myself.

Comment: You need to be more specific when creating a post. For your latest comment, check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#custom-if-statements) to create a custom directive so you can ease you the validation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if your validation process is done in the AppServiceProvider file or in the controller.

But I think after the validation in the controller, you can use the function

```php
Auth::setUser($user)
```